# Intuition of Negative entropy as a Fenchel conjugate of logistic cost function

Tags: statistics, optimization, convex-optimization, entropy, logistic-regression

Let us first recall the **logistic cost function**

$$f_1(x)=\log(1+e^x)$$

and the **negative entropy function**

$$f_2(y)=y\log(y)+(1-y)\log(1-y).$$

Here $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm and $x\in \mathbb R$ and $y\in (0,1)$.

We also recall the **Fenchel conjugate** function $f^*$ of function $f$ as

$$f^*(y):=\sup_{x\in \mathbb R} \, \, yx - f(x).$$

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Table_of_selected_convex_conjugates), we know that
$$f_1^*(y)=f_2(y).$$

The notion of logistic cost and negative entropy have their own meaning and seem to be independent. I am so surprising when the Fenchel conjugate can establish their relation! Is there an intuition behind such relation?

Comment: This is really a nice question for which I have no answer yet. Note that it is not restricted to natural logarithm and exp: in basis 2 the negative entropy is
$g_2(y)=y\log_2(y)+(1-y)\,\log_2(1-y)$ and 
its Fenchel conjugate is $g_2^*(x)=\log_2(1+2^x).$

Comment: @KurtG. thank you for your remark!